# Why pytesseract does not recognise single digits?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am performing ocr on a site and specifically on these two images:
[image: image1.png]

[image: image2.png]

I am fairly new to OCR, I use the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

my_image = '....png'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(my_image))
```

In the second image it recognises everything except the single digits 3, 4, 5, 6.

In the first image it does not recognises the single digits too.

I preprocess the images by resizing them, inverting them and using threshold.

It's a standard font so I know there are other ways to do this, but until a certain degree it works for me, so I want to keep it simple before going to something more advanced.

Comment: To clarify, it's not recognizing 3, 4, 5, 6 in _only_ the second image - first one, it doesn't recognize _any_ single digit number right?

Comment: Yes, no single digits in any image.

Comment: The digits seem to show up using psm 6.

Comment: The single digits appear too ?

Comment: try to convert your image to tiff using ImageMagick, then test on terminal: tesseract yourimag.tiff output.txt

Comment: I tried using tesseract in command line with -psm 6 and it works, but it doesn't work if I do the same in pytesseract: text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(my_image), config='-psm 6')

Answer (score 3):

For the both image, you can

1. upsample the image : For accurate recognition.
2. apply [simple-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html): To display the features.

For the first image, you can take part of the image selecting a range:

[image]

Result will be:

```
62001
33000
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img1 = cv2.imread("lNKH4.png")  # "FX2in.png"
gry1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry1.shape[:2]
gry1 = cv2.resize(gry1, (w*2, h*2))
gry1 = gry1[30:(h*2), w+50:w*2]
thr1 = cv2.threshold(gry1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr1, config="--psm 6 digits")
print(txt1)
cv2.imshow("thr1", thr1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For the 2nd image:

[image]

Result will be:

```
2
3 1.28 4.50 9.00
4 2.00 3.75 3.00
5 3.50 4.33 1.72
6 7.00 6.00 1.28
```

Same code, just remove the following line:

```py
gry1 = gry1[30:(h*2), w+50:w*2]
```