# Using Tesseract to recognize time from an image

Tags: python, tesseract

I want to read the time from the image below using Tesseract. My code is:

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string('test.png')
print(text)
```

The image is as below:
[image]

But for some reason, this program doesn't work, and the text is always a space. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the flag `config="--psm 6"` and it should work. This specifies that you have a single uniform block of text. 7 also work which is for a single line of uniform text.

```py
print(pytesseract.image_to_string('test.png', config="--psm 6"))

# prints "06-04-2021 11:27:17\n\x0c"
```

See this other post for another example https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179528/15271127

EDIT: Also see this website if you want more options https://muthu.co/all-tesseract-ocr-options/